# The option formatting.local in vscode-go its working?

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm using [vscode-go extension](https://github.com/golang/vscode-go) and reading the options I see than exist the [`formatting.local`](https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/blob/master/docs/settings.md#formattinglocal) option but this option seems not be working Im trying to configure like this...

**settings.json**

```
"go.formatTool": "goimports",
"go.formatting.local": "github.com/mycompany/my_app"
```

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"formatting.local" is a gopls setting. https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/blob/master/docs/settings.md#settings-for-gopls So, please add it inside the `"gopls"` block for now.

```
"gopls": {
   "formatting.local": "github.com/mycompany/my_app"
}
```